# Как добавить на изображение строчку текста? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, обработка-изображений, рисование

Есть картинка, требуется на нее добавить строчку текста, которую можно задать. Как это сделать с помощью Python? Требуется создать бота для ВК, на примере вот это бота. https://vk.com/memes_bot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Например, используйте библиотеку `PIL`.

Самый [простой пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c688b2bc6d9181ccfac12f4fe0f21e0e41a9273b/pil_pillow__examples/simple_draw__hello_world/main.py) рисования:

```
# pip install Pillow
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.open("images.jpg")

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 25)
drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
drawer.text((50, 100), "Hello World!\nПривет мир!", font=font, fill='black')
    
image.save('new_img.jpg')
image.show()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как добавить картинку через URL-cсылку?

Comment: @FEgor, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23489503/5741205

Comment: @FEgor, вам уже подсказали, если непонятно, то лучше создайте отдельный вопрос. В комментариях такие вещи не показать